# Issue Using SQL Replace Function with Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, replace, ssms

Essentially, I'm trying to loop through the contents of `@sprocs` variable, implement the replace function, and print the respective changes. When I execute the code, the `@spname` variable is printed off, just not with the expected result.

```
declare @sprocs cursor
declare @spname nvarchar(max)

set @sprocs = cursor for
select ROUTINE_DEFINITION
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'Procedure' AND
ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%someString%'


open @sprocs
fetch next from @sprocs into @spname
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    set @spname = replace(@spname, '%someString%', 'Hello')
    print @spname
    fetch next from @sprocs into @spname
end
```

Expected result would look like this:

```
Before
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, someString adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco someString nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. someString sint occaecat cupidatat non someString, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

```
After
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Hello adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco Hello nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Hello sint occaecat cupidatat non Hello, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

I thought - initially - that is might be an issue with `@spname` variable type, but since it's declared as an `nvarchar(max)`, I can't see that being the issue.

What's preventing the expected print out?

Comment: you might want to use `replace(@spname, 'someString', 'Hello')`  instead of `replace(@spname, '%someString%', 'Hello')` .. the string to be replaced should be declared **literally** .. wildcards don't work here.

Comment: @vpk, that worked. I clearly don't understand how wildcards work. I know you stated that it's because the string I'm looking for in this case was declared literally, but why wouldn't wildcards work in this situation? Wouldn't the wildcards indicate that it could be found within any part of the string?

Comment: @vpk, if you add your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @cwanjt You need the wildcards to define a search pattern. `%a` would mean *ends with "a"*, while `%a%` means *"a" is somewhere in the middle and `a%` means "starts with "a". A `REPLACE` will find and replace the given string wherever it is located - even several times. If you'd **know** that the string to change is at the beginning or at the end, you'd probably use `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` to cut this part off and concatenate the rest with your new string.

Comment: Do you really need a cursor for that? Why not just use a simple select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to not using wildcards in your searchstring, you also really don't need a cursor for this.  SQL works on the basis of data sets and applies anything you do in a standard `select` statement to all rows that are returned.

In light of this, your statement should just be:

```
select ROUTINE_DEFINITION
      ,replace(ROUTINE_DEFINITION,'someString','Hello') as ReplacedValues
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_TYPE = 'Procedure'
  and ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%someString%'
```

which will apply the `replace` function to each and every value of `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` returned by the query.